# Azure Data Factory- How to create a table from one snowflake account into another snowflake account using data factory?

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a table in a target snowflake account say snowflake_acccount1 from source snowflake account snowflake_acccount2 using data factory copy activity. But that didn't work as the data set/linked services can support only respective account at a time each.

Below is the query that i want to use to create a table from a snowflake_acccount2 in snowflake_acccount1 using azure data factory

```
create table if not exist snowflake_acccount1_schema.table1 as select * from snowflake_acccount2_schema.table1
```

I tried using script activity again that only support for one dataset to connect at a time.

## Due to privacy and confidential, i cannot share the pipeline diagram

is there any way to achieve this using ADF?

Comment: Hari, why not do it entirely within Snowflake?

Either SHARE the table or REPLICATE it. Since this is an ETL pipeline your best choice is probably sharing, you won't have to unload and reload the data making it both faster and cheaper.

Comment: ok .. Actually this is supposed to done  by a  pipeline user and should be part of an existing pipeline which does copy activity for the available table.

Comment: You don't need to copy the data from one database to another with Snowflake. If you SHARE the data it is a live view within the consumer account. You can probably skip that copy step entirely, and simply move on with the rest of the pipeline. I know you said the pipeline is sensitive, but a similar example would really help :)

Comment: i mean to say the ADF pipeline.. There is some restriction to share the data hence we used ADF update latest record in to the target warehouse. in that case, does ADF support to do that?

Answer (score 0):

***There is no such way to query another database or Copy table from one snowflake account to another in ADF as in snowflake linked service, we supposed to give the default database to be used and copy activity cannon create the table in snowflake it will just transfer the data.***

**The workaround is to use staging in snowflake as below:**

- First create an external stage in snowflake on Azure Blob storage. you can follow this [document](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-azure-config) to get some idea.
- Then Load your data from source snowflake account to Azure blob storage (same for which you created staging in snowflake) in Parquet format.
- After that based on that newly created file in Azure blob storage you can create a table and copy data into it using below query

```sql
create or replace table tablename  
using template (  
select array_agg(object_construct(*))  
from table(  
infer_schema(  
location=>’@stagedcopy/address’,  
file_format=>’my_parquet_format’  
)  
));
```

You can refer this [document](https://medium.com/snowflake/seamless-migration-to-snowflake-using-adf-script-activity-schema-detection-25475ea86a09) for more information.